# Python. Как завершить выполнение exec() через заданное время?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Здрасте! Хочу сделать на питоне код для автопроверки работы программы. Допустим у меня есть код, который я запускаю через `exec()`. Как я могу сделать, чтобы по прошествии 1 секунды программа закачивала его выполнение и выводила `Time limit exceeded`?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Может, узнать время вначале цикла с помощью `time.time()`и постоянно проверять его?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так можно сделать:

- создать отдельный процесс, который будет выполнять `exec`
- подождать секунду и, если процесс с `exec` ещё не завершился, прекратить его

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep

def run_exec():
    print('запуск процесса')
    exec('sleep(3)')
    print('процесс завершен')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Process(target=run_exec)
    t.start()
    sleep(2)
    if t.is_alive():
        t.terminate()
        print('процесс прерван')
```

Можете поиграться со значениями `sleep` в основном коде и в процессе, чтобы убедиться, что всё работает - либо процесс успевает отработать за определённое время, либо он принудительно прекращается.

Comment: Может я туплю, но при запуске этого кода питон выдаёт следующую [ошибку](https://pastebin.com/iDkDNgLq)

Comment: @Soup Поправил код, попробуйте так

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь работает